# Permutation - 17 women and 21 men to form a committee of size 7

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

How many committees are possible?

I added the total number of women ($17$) and the total number of men ($21$) to get $38$ total people.

I used this as my $n$ or objects.  I then subtracted my $r$ from $n$ and got $31$.

So $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!} = \frac{38!}{31!}= 63,606,090,245$

This number seems too large, but perhaps it's not?  Did I calculate this properly?

Comment: This is a combination question and not permutation, hence the correct formula for combinations which is, $\frac{n!}{r! (n - r)!}$ must be used instead :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that this would be combination since the order is not taken into account. $$\displaystyle \binom{38}{7} = \dfrac{38!}{7!31!} = \dfrac{32\cdot 33\cdot 34\cdot 35\cdot 36\cdot 37\cdot 38}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5\cdot 6\cdot 7}$$

Comment: Using the formula you listed I got $12,620,256.001$.  Does this sound correct?

Comment: Its $12,620,256$ exactly...